# Django - annotate against a prefetch QuerySet?

Tags: django

Is it possible to annotate/count against a prefetched query?

My initial query below, is based on circuits, then I realised that if a site does not have any circuits I won't have a 'None' Category which would show a site as Down.

```
conn_data = Circuits.objects.all() \
    .values('circuit_type__circuit_type') \
    .exclude(active_link=False) \
    .annotate(total=Count('circuit_type__circuit_type')) \
    .order_by('circuit_type__monitor_priority')
```

So I changed to querying sites and using prefetch, which now has an empty circuits_set for any site that does not have an active link. Is there a Django way of creating the new totals against that circuits_set within conn_data? I was going to loop through all the sites manually and add the totals that way but wanted to know if there was a way to do this within the QuerySet instead?

my end result should have a something like:

```
[
    {'circuit_type__circuit_type': 'Fibre', 'total': 63},
    {'circuit_type__circuit_type': 'DSL', 'total': 29},
    {'circuit_type__circuit_type': 'None', 'total': 2}
]
```

prefetch query:

```
conn_data = SiteData.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'circuits_set',
        queryset=Circuits.objects.exclude(
            active_link=False).select_related('circuit_type'),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got what I wanted with this, probably a better way of doing it but it works never the less:

```
from collections import Counter
import operator

class ConnData(object):
    def __init__(self, priority='', c_type='', count=0 ):
        self.priority = priority
        self.c_type = c_type
        self.count = count
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.c_type)  
# get all the site data
conn_data = SiteData.objects.exclude(Q(site_type__site_type='Data Centre') | Q(site_type__site_type='Factory')) \
                    .prefetch_related(
                                Prefetch(
                                'circuits_set',
                                queryset=Circuits.objects.exclude(active_link=False).select_related('circuit_type'),
                                )
                        )
# create a list for the conns
conns = []
# add items to list of dictionaries with all required fields
for conn in conn_data:
    try:
        conn_type = conn.circuits_set.all()[0].circuit_type.circuit_type
        prioritiy = conn.circuits_set.all()[0].circuit_type.monitor_priority
        conns.append({'circuit_type' : conn_type, 'priority' : prioritiy})
    except:
        # create category for down sites
        conns.append({'circuit_type' : 'Down', 'priority' : 10})
# crate new list for class data
conn_counts = []
# create counter data
conn_count_data = Counter(((d['circuit_type'], d['priority']) for d in conns))
# loop through counter data and add classes to list
for val, count in conn_count_data.items():
    cc = ConnData()
    cc.priority = val[1]
    cc.c_type = val[0]
    cc.count = count
    conn_counts.append(cc)
# sort the classes by priority
conn_counts = sorted(conn_counts, key=operator.attrgetter('priority'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work. Its debatable whether it should work. Let's refer to what `prefetch_related` does.

> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

So what happens here is that two queries are dispatched and two lists are realized. These lists are then partitioned in memory and grouped to the correct parent records.

`Count()` and `annotate()` are directives to the DBMS that resolve to SQL

```
Select Count(id) from conn_data
```

Because of the way `annotate` and `prefetch_related` work I think its unlikely they will play nice together. `prefetch_related` is just a convenience though. From a practical perspective running two separate ORM queries and assigning them to `SiteData` records yourself is effectively the same thing. So something like ...

```
#Gets all Circuits counted and grouped by SiteData 

Circuits.objects.values('sitedata_id)'.exclude(active_link=False).select_related('circuit_type').annotate(Count('site_data_id'));
```

Then you just loop over your `SiteData` records and assign the counts.

Comment: if I get the circuits, then this will exclude a site_data that does not have any active_links. I need to identify when a site has zero active links, but I don't want to get none active links where the site has one if that makes sense?

Comment: Any sites not in that list but in the full `SiteData` list have zero active links.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_list()

Comment: I didn't test that ORM, you might have to move `values()` to the end. If you get it to work edit the working line into this answer please.